# Order By for NVARCHAR column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a NVARCHAR(255) column in a SQL Server 2005 that contain either letters or numbers.

```
Declare @Temp Table(Name NVARCHAR(255))

Insert Into @Temp Values('1')
Insert Into @Temp Values('2')
Insert Into @Temp Values('3')
Insert Into @Temp Values('10')
Insert Into @Temp Values('aaaa')
Insert Into @Temp Values('ccaaaaa')
Insert Into @Temp Values('cca')
Insert Into @Temp Values('cccc')
Insert Into @Temp Values('ccaa')

Select * From  @Temp Order by Name
```

This query returns bad result. Can somebody explain why?
Also, can somebody tell me which query to use to sort values.
I want to get next sequence:

```
1
2
3
10
aaaa
cca
ccaa
ccaaaaa
cccc
```

Thanks

Comment: Query returns correct result. Database use Danish alphabet!

Answer (score 4):

@Shark showed you why, I'll show you a work around in your `SELECT` to get you the results you want:

```
Select * From  @Temp 
Order by 
    case isnumeric(name) 
       when 1 then cast(name as int) 
       else 999999999999999 end, 
    name
```

Comment: @Shark It was a team work, while you were working on "why", I was working on "how" :)

Comment: Haha good point, T.E.A.M. (Together Everybody Achieves More). :)

Comment: Thanks. Numbers are OK now, But letters are not in desired sentence. I forgot to mension. I have express edition of SQL Server 2005. Is it problem?

Comment: @SrdjanDejanovic This fix should work. What do you mean by "letters are not in desired sentence"?

Comment: @SrdjanDejanovic - Did you miss the last line: `name`?

Answer (score 3):

The actual order of results will be this:

```
1
10
2
3
aaaa
cca
ccaa
ccaaaaa
cccc
```

And SQL Server is sorting it like that because it is getting sorted based on their character values.  In other words, the character `1` comes before `2`, as `10` will also come before `2`.

So the reason you're getting odd sorting is because your are ordering by string values, not numeric.

**EDIT**: Please see Adrian's answer to the workaround.

Comment: I'll upvote if you propose a workaround *coughcoughCASEcoughcough* :)

Comment: @JNK Ah, Adrian beat me to it! :)

Comment: @JNK You might want to look at my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks. Numbers are OK now, But letters are not in desired sentence. I forgot to mension. I have express edition of SQL Server 2005. Is it problem?

Comment: @SrdjanDejanovic Well the char value of the letters will follow the char value of the numbers, which is why the letter strings come after the number strings.